# Kubernetes no matches for kind "AzureKeyVaultSecret" in version "v1"

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-keyvault

I am trying to link kubernetes with azure key vault. while trying to create an AzureKeyVaultSecret with yml file, referring https://mrdevops.io/introducing-azure-key-vault-to-kubernetes-931f82364354

but its giving error as

```
error: unable to recognize "test.yml":no matches for kind "AzureKeyVaultSecret" in version "v1"
```

yml file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: AzureKeyVaultSecret
metadata:
   name: azure-keyvault-certificate
   namespace: default
spec:
  vault:
    name: my-keyvault-name
    object:
      type: certificate
       name: my-kv-cert
output:
  secret:
    name: my_kv-cert
    type: kubernetes.io/tls
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you deploy the below components

Azure Key Vault Controller —synchronize Azure Key Vault secrets into native Kubernetes secrets, and keeps them updated

Azure Key Vault Env Injector — transparently inject Azure Key Vault Secrets into applications running in Kubernetes containers, without revealing its content to Kubernetes resources, Etcd or its users

deploy the files from [here](https://github.com/SparebankenVest/azure-key-vault-to-kubernetes/tree/master/installation).

Comment: i have the azure key vault and kubernetes ready, then followed the above link, but how to deploy these components?

Comment: follow the link in my answer

Comment: hi Ekambaram, i have executed the deployment and rbac files in installation and was successful in creating controllers and readers. again when i tried to create secret same error is there..

Comment: are you able to list the new object using kubectl get AzureKeyVaultSecret

Comment: Thanks Ekambaram, now able to create the secret and is displayed on the above command

Answer (score 0):

if you wants to use Secrets connectiong with your Azure KeyVault, try to read this

But, the version in your manifests file needs to be this:

apiVersion: spv.no/v2beta1

Official Documentation
https://akv2k8s.io/how-it-works/